# AEM: using sling error handler: how do I redirect error originating from specific pages to a specific error page only

Tags: aem, sling, aem-6

Using sling error handler: How do I identify and redirect error originating from specific web pages node and all node below it to a specific error page only ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at a pure sling implementation then you can customise the default error handler as per the document:

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/errorhandling.html#default-handler

If this is AEM related (hazarding a guess from your question tag), I would recommend looking at ACS AEM commons error handling:

https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/errorpagehandler.html

If none of these works, or are inadequate for your needs then a custom error handler can be built to implement your error handling and defaulting logic.